# Add mouse navigation to IDD figure

Tags: javascript, charts

I use [IDD](https://github.com/predictionmachines/InteractiveDataDisplay) to draw a bar chart.

I described a figure in HTML page like

`<div data-idd-plot="figure">
    <div data-idd-plot="markers"></div>
</div>`

How can I add mouse navgation (interactivity) to this figure?

I do not want to use **chart** instead of **figure** as chart along with mouse navigation adds axes and legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code assigns gesture source for the figure navigation:

```
var figure = InteractiveDataDisplay.asPlot("figure")
figure.navigation.gestureSource = 
    InteractiveDataDisplay.Gestures.getGesturesStream(figure.centralPart);
```

After this you'll be able to navigate over the figure element, but there will be no gridlines, you still have to add them manually since you use the figure plot.